# Repeat rows in a data frame according to a vector

Tags: r, dataframe, repeat

I have a data frame and would like to repeat each row by each element in a pre defined vector.

for example if I have a matrix (I use matrix for example)

```
     matrix(c(1,2,3,2,1,3),2)
         [,1] [,2] [,3]
  [1,]    1    3    1
  [2,]    2    2    3
```

I would like this to return

```
matrix(c(1,1,2,2,3,3,2,2,1,1,3,3),4)
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    1
[2,]    1    3    1
[3,]    2    2    3
[4,]    2    2    3
```

if the vector was vec = c(2,2).
my vector has varying size elements. Sorry, I am new to coding.

Answer (score 3):

Repeat over the row numbers. In your example:

```
base = matrix(c(1,2,3,2,1,3),2)
rows = 1:nrow(base)
index= rep(rows, c(2,2))
base[index,]
```